# Navigation between view controllers

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios9

On my application, I have four view controllers (VC):

- HOME
- MESSAGES
- PROFIL
- SETTINGS

On each VC, an opaque bar bottom with four bar button items for each VC (home, messages, profil, settings).

When I tap on one bar button item, I manage the navigation with a segue (show) and it loads the selected VC.

I would like to find a way to not load again a VC already loaded one time.
For example:

- The app is launched
- HOME VC is loaded and appears
- User taps on PROFIL
- PROFIL VC is loaded and appears
- User taps on HOME
- HOME VC appears without calling `viewDidLoad` method, because it has already been loaded four steps ago

I tried with all types of segues (show, present modally, etc.) and with `presentViewController` method, but each time the `viewDidLoad` method is called.

Is there an easy way to do this or do I have to manage this with a boolean to indicate that the view was already loaded?

I would like a menu like [WhatsApp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp) application has for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WhatsApp uses a **Tab Bar** at the bottom. Are you using Toolbar? ViewDidLoad only executes once per view unless you unload the view from memory.

The easiest way to adapt your app is to just add a **Tab Bar Controller** in your app and then delete the 2 automatically added view controllers and set a **relationship** (just like a segue; it's below segue types) between each view controller and the tab bar controller. To change the icons, modify them in the **Tab Bar Controller View**. Then segues will work automagically just like in WhatsApp. :)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, and really easy to implement in my actual project. Thanks!